# STM32 writing to EEPROM(I2C) / generating datas by I2C failed with registers

Tags: stm32, i2c, low-level, stm32f4, eeprom

I am trying to learn how to write some datas to eeprom by I2C and I just adjust the clocks configuration on cubemx and then try to handle with all other things with registers. But something went wrong and maybe you guys help me by sheding light on this.

I adjusted the APB1 and APB2 peripheral clocks to 16 MHz by using cubemx.

At the end of main function, microcontroller was supposed to send/generate “0x50” and “0x01” bytes, but when I look on logic analyser I just see the 0x50 , I couldn’t see the 0x01 after 0x50.  My first aim is to generate some bytes from microcontroller by using I2C , after that I actually will consider eeprom.

```
    /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #include "main.h"


    /* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
    void SystemClock_Config(void);
    static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

    int main(void)
    {

        int slave_adress = 0x50; // eeprom adress
        int word_adress = 0x01;  // I want to write in this register adress in eeprom.
              int data = 0x30;  // the data I want to write



      /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

      /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
      HAL_Init(); 
      /* Configure the system clock */
      SystemClock_Config();

            MX_GPIO_Init(); // it has nothing important.


        RCC->AHB1ENR |= 1<<1; //enable port B


        RCC->APB1ENR |= 1<<21; // enable  i2c_1 





        GPIOB->MODER    = 0x82000; // made PB6-I2C1_CLK ve PB9-I2C_SDA pins as  alternate function

          GPIOB->AFR[0] = 0x4000000; //  made pb6 as af4 (i2c1_scl)
        GPIOB->AFR[1]   = 0x40;      //    made pb9 as af4 (i2c1_sda)



    GPIOB->OTYPER |= 0x240; //made PB6 and PB9 as open drain 


    GPIOB->PUPDR = 0x00;



    I2C1->CR2 = 0x0010; // made 16MHz clock hsi
    I2C1->CCR = 0x0050; ////SM Mod, duty=0 pclk=16mhz
    I2C1->TRISE = 0x0011; //1000 ns / 62.5 ns = 16 + 1

        I2C1->CR1    = 0x0001;      //enable I2C


I2C1->CR1 |= 1<<8; //I2C Start

            while (!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0001));// //wait for start bit, //subsequent access of data register will clear start bit




            I2C1->DR = slave_adress;                // Write to I2C Address register
            while (!(I2C1->SR1 & 0x0002));  // wait until adress sent – (EV_6 – reference manual)




            I2C1->DR = word_adress; // (EV8_1 – reference manual)

            while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<7))); // Wait TxE bit set






    }

    /**
      * @brief System Clock Configuration
      * @retval None
      */
    void SystemClock_Config(void)
    {
      RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
      RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

      /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
      */
      __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);
      /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
      */
      RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
      if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
      */
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                                  |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

      if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
    }

    /**
      * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
      * @param None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
    {

      /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();

    }
```

Comment: You don't send the address through DR register but through CR2 register.

Comment: Check the HAL source code. It is good to understand precisely how the peripheral is working (in addition to the reference manual obvisouly).

Comment: Hi @GuillaumePetitjean, firstly thank you for your answer, but I could not see the anything in CR2 register related with sending adress etc.  , and yes hal source is good place to understand well, but I could not get answer from it :)

Comment: Function `I2C_TransferConfig` : you write the slave address to registre I2C_CR2. I've not worked on I2C for a long time, check in the ref manual